# Remove line of text from a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Ive scoured for days online and have not found what I am looking for.

I am reading in a file line by line, grabbing the first token which is a filename, then running that file.  After running the file I would move it to an archive folder and delete the line of text from the file before reading the next line.

I need to remove that line of text AFTER the file is run but cannot figure out how to do that

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Get time date in special format
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/: " %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

REM Loop through each line
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (./ready/input.txt) DO (

    REM>output.txt

    REM Run the file
        call .\ready\%%i || goto :error

    REM Move the file to archive folder
    move .\ready\%%i .\archive\%mydate%_%mytime%_%%j_%%k_%%i

    REM ***Remove the current line of text from input.txt ****

)
goto :EOF

:error
echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%.
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Edit:  More info. What I am trying to do, is track the files that did not run... so there might be 6 lines of files, it might read line 1 run the file, read line 2 run the file, then cannot find file 3 so it exits... i need to be able to output the last 4 lines

Comment: write/copy to input.txt2 and then copy that onto input.txt. (you can't edit the text and save it to the same file...")

Comment: @Dru What I am trying to do, is track the files that did not run... so there might be 6 lines of files, it might read line 1 run the file, read line 2 run the file, then cannot find file 3 so it exits... i need to be able to output the last 4 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Get time date in special format
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/: " %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)

REM Loop through each line
set "errorfound="
del newfile.txt >nul 2>nul
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=, " %%i IN (./ready/input.txt) DO (

 REM YOU DO REALISE THIS NEXT LINE WILL RE-CREATE THE FILE EACH ITERATION DON'T YOU?
 REM>output.txt

 REM Run the file
 if not defined errorfound (
  call .\ready\%%i
  if errorlevel 1 (
   REM PRESUME ERRORLEVEL1+=fail
   set errorfound=Y
   ) else (
    REM Move the file to archive folder
    move .\ready\%%i .\archive\%mydate%_%mytime%_%%j_%%k_%%i
  )
 )
 if defined errorfound >>newfile.txt echo %%i %%j %%k
)

if defined errorfound echo error found-unprocessed lines in newfile.txt
goto :EOF
```

Presuming you want to stop on the first error, the above should work.

`errorfound` is set once er, an error is found. `if defined` works on the current value of the variable, so after the first error is found, it reproduces the significant portions of the input data lines to a new file.